# Fetch first 10 results from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

Is there a way we can fetch first 10 results from a list. Something like this maybe?

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

list.fetch(10)
```

Answer (score 463, accepted):

```
list[:10]
```

will give you the first 10 elements of this list using slicing.

However, note, it's best ***not*** to use `list` as a variable identifier as it's already used by Python: [list()](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-list)

To find out more about this type of operation, you might find this [tutorial on lists](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) helpful and this link: [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Comment: Note that this creates a copy of the first 10 elements. Depending on your needs you might prefer lazy, non-copying slicing with itertools.islice.

Comment: @thg435 -- This doesn't create a copy of the elements in the list, only a new reference to them.  It does however, create a new list ...

Comment: @mgilson: it depends on what you understand under "element". Python containers always hold pointers to objects, and this creates 10 new pointers (+ one new list object).

Comment: @thg435 -- python has no pointers.  (if you want pointers, you use C ;)  python has references.  the point here is that you don't create new objects, only new references to them...We're saying the same thing, but the way your original statement was written was misleading (at least to me) so I thought I would clarify.

Comment: @mgilson: agreed, I should have better written "creates a copy of that part of the list".

Answer (score 39):

check this

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    
list[0:10]
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: explicit vs implicit: use explicit, this slicing conforms to python zen code! :) more clear.

Comment: To be clear, the `0` is not required here, it's implied. The way I think of it is this is saying "from 0 to 10" while `list[:10]` would mean "up to 10", which is simpler.

Answer (score 20):

The [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module has lots of great stuff in it. So if a standard slice (as used by Levon) does not do what you want, then try the `islice` function:

```
from itertools import islice
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
iterator = islice(l, 10)
for item in iterator:
    print item
```

Comment: list(islice(map((lambda x: x**2 + 1),count()),10)) is an example where a regular slice won't work.

Answer (score 13):

Use the slicing operator:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
list[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `slice()` object.

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

# first 10 elements
sl = slice(10)
lst[sl]   # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# first 5 even-indexed elements
sl = slice(0, 10, 2)
lst[sl]   # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

An advantage of it over slicing the list directly (e.g. `list[:10]`) is that the slice object can be stored and used later (on this list or any other sliceable object).