# How to get the first to some index values in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list = [1, 6, 5, 7, 8]
num = int(input("Enter a value") #lets say 3 for now
```

How do I get the values from the start of the list to the `num`?

Output should be:

```
[1, 6, 5]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Fetch first 10 results from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897339/python-fetch-first-10-results-from-a-list)

Comment: it does. Thanks to all who answered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6045800). Slicing allows you to take a certain range of numbers from a list.

```
list = [1, 6, 5, 7, 8]
num = int(input("Enter a value")

print(list[0:num])
```

That should return : `[1,6,5]`

Hope that helps!

Comment: oh ok. Just a small side question though. When you wrote : list[0:num], does the 0:num always have to be in those brackets? ( [ ] )

Comment: @Eren145 As for as my python knowledge goes, Im pretty sure that it needs to be in those brackets. That's the correct syntax for slicing. You can learn more about slicing and lists here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a single line of code,

```
data = [1, 6, 5, 7, 8]
print(data[:int(input('Enter the number'))])
```

Comment: It's just a slicing mechanism in python. if you want to get a range of items from a list You can use slicing mechanism. Here I am passing the integer getting from the input to the list slicing. data[:] will get the all items from the list just like an exact copy of the list. if you pass the input as 3 then it will give you a new list of items from position 0th index to the 3rd index.

Answer (score 0):

`list[:3]`

You can use [`slicing`](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) to achieve this. Note: Don't name your list `list`! Please name it something else, as you will not be able to call `list()` anymore.

Comment: The OP is relying on user input. Hardcoding `3` seems a bit problematic

Comment: you can replace 3 with num, if the value of num changes right?

Comment: Yes, of course. I used 3 as an example so you can understand how slicing works. an integer variable will do the same job.

Comment: @Eren145 Yes you can replace it with num as long as it's an integer. It will not work if left a string.